# Azure DevOps Build and Release pipeline artifact name variable

Tags: azure-devops

Trying to do something simple. Either access the name of the artifact from my release pipeline via some [predefined variable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables), or create a variable for both my build and release pipeline for the artifact name. I don't want to hard-code it.
I would like my build and release pipelines decoupled.

[image: Variable Group Details]

Publish Build Artifacts YAML:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: 'dist'
    **ArtifactName: $(Storage.ArtifactName)**
    publishLocation: 'Container'
  displayName: 'publish artifact'
```

Output:

```
##[section]Starting: publish artifact
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish build artifacts
Description  : Publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines or a Windows file share
Version      : 1.158.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts
==============================================================================
##[section]Async Command Start: Upload Artifact
Uploading 10 files
File upload succeed.
**Upload '/home/vsts/work/1/s/dist' to file container: '#/3928702/$(Storage.ArtifactName)'**
Associated artifact 10 with build 58
##[section]Async Command End: Upload Artifact
##[section]Finishing: publish artifact
```

Comment: What is the preferred outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add:

```
variables:
- group: front_end-storage
```

At the top of my pipeline for the pipeline to pick up on the variables and authorize the group.